# Wiki style text formatting

Tags: asp.net, html, .net, wiki, text-formatting

I'm looking for some kind of text-parser for ASP.NET that can make HTML from some style of text that uses a special format. Like in Wiki's there is some special syntax for headings and such. I have tried to look on google, but I did not found anything for .NET.

Do someone know about a library for .NET that can parse the text to HTML wiki-style? I't don't have to be the same syntax as a Wiki? If no, how whould be the best way to design such a system your self?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

how about the Markdown that StackOverflow uses?

http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

from their home page:

> Thus, “Markdown” is two things: (1) a
>   plain text formatting syntax; and (2)
>   a software tool, written in Perl, that
>   converts the plain text formatting to
>   HTML.

Comment: Thanks. Found that when i searched for a solution, but did not know there was a .NET Version of it. +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

For the server side, you can use the Markdown.Net library from Milan Negovan : http://www.aspnetresources.com/blog/markdown_announced.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Markdown is great - very intuitive syntax, and you have [WMD - this terrific editing tool](http://wmd-editor.com/) that I'm typing into now.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to *strongly* recommend Textile over Markdown.  [Textile.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/textilenet) should do what you want.

Why?  I like Textile's syntax better, and I think it's easier for users to learn and use.  There's no single large reason - just a lot of small things.

In Markdown you can do *`*italics*`* and **`**bold**`** easily, but the syntax seems arbitrary.  Compare to the equivalent syntax in Textile for *`_italics_`* and **`*bold*`**, which mirrors the conventional way to indicate those modifiers in plain text formats.

Or for another example, in Textile you make an ordered list by prefixing each item with an '#'.  In Markdown, you prefix it with "n.", where n is any integer.  Markdown is trying to imitate the syntax people use in flat text files when writing lists (which is nice), but it means that this Markdown code:

```
3.  Test1
2.  Test2
1.  Test3
```

Is rendered as this:

> 1. Test1
> 2. Test2
> 3. Test3

Basically, Markdown asks you for a number, which it then ignores.  That seems inelegant to me, although I couldn't explain why precisely.

Textile also does tables (and wish a nicely compact syntax).  Markdown doesn't.  There's a few other minor points, but I think that covers most of it.  :)

Comment: it'd be more convincing with some actual *reasons* other than "I like it better". Just sayin'!

Comment: Sadly, those really are the only reasons.  I learned Textile faster than Markdown, and I think the syntax is prettier.  *shrug*